# « Éducation de l'amour » ou « éducation à l'amour »

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques

Existe-t-il une différence entre « l'éducation de l'amour/l'éthique » et « l'éducation à l'amour/l'éthique » ? Peut-on utiliser les deux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« éducation à l'amour/éthique » : « éducation qui a pour objet d'enseignement l'amour/éthique »

« éducation de l'amour/éthique » : « éducation qui a pour élève l'amour/éthique »

Le deuxième sens parait saugrenu, ce qui explique qu'on ne le recontre pas.

Comment: "Éducation de l'amour" pourrait aussi peut-être vouloir dire "éducation par l'amour", mais aussi un peu saugrenu.

Comment: Merci ! C'est très clair :)

Comment: @Frank avez-vous un exemple qui collerait à ce sens? J'y ai pensé mais n'en ai pas trouvé.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Non, pas d'exemple. En théorie c'est possible, je peux le concevoir, mais ce serait bel et bien un peu tordu.